# Flutter dialog always refreshing on select an item of auto complete text view in opened dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am struggling to select an item from auto complete text view which is placed under the dialog. When I search something it is showing me suggestions but item not keeps selected when I going to tap on one item because I noticed that whole dialog is refreshing on item click of auto complete text view.

> I have create a separate screen for this dialog also but still same
> issue is coming.

```
class AssetEditDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new AssetEditDialogState();
}

class AssetEditDialogState extends State<AssetEditDialog> {
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  TextEditingController roomController = new TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _roomFocusNode = new FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    roomController.text =
        Global.scanAssetResult.assetRoom.isEmpty && Global.scanAssetResult.assetRoom == null ? Global.notAvailable : Global.scanAssetResult.assetRoom;

    AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField;
    GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<String>> key = new GlobalKey();

    return Dialog(
      child: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Asset Number",
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
            ),
            Text(
              Global.scanAssetResult.assetNo,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
            ),
            Text(
              "Asset Serial Number",
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
            ),
            Text(
              Global.scanAssetResult.assetSerialNo,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
            ),
            Text(
              "Asset Sector",
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<String>(
              key: key,
              suggestions: Global.sectorList,
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                  hintText: 'Search here',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              itemFilter: (item, query) {
                return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
              },
              itemSorter: (a, b) {
                return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
              },
              clearOnSubmit: false,
              itemSubmitted: (item) {
                setState(() {
                  try {
                    searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item;
                    return;
                  } on Exception catch (exception) {
                    Global.writeErrorLog(true, "Autocomplete text view ", exception.toString());
                  }
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      item,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is screenshot :

[image]

Please give a proper solution to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: share code snipshot

Comment: @RahulKushwaha I have edited my answer with code.

Comment: could you share a screenshot of the problem (from the app)

Comment: @AmineDakhli I have added the screenshot above. Please take a review once.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha Can you please help me? I need it urgent. Thanks.

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati I see your code but cant find any error. Will you please see and analize  the log error  while Dialog recreate when selecting item from AutoComplete Text.  You can try one thing also try make change Dialog to Container in body. and call Dialog firsttime  from setState.(){}. Try change from Dialod to Container  once . if issues not resolve ,let me know.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha  I have created separate screen for this dialog but still same issue is coming. Can you please give other suggestion?

Comment: I got the answer. Please see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. Just look below code:

Just remove below lines :

```
           setState(() { //Remove this line
              try {
                searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item;
                return;
              } on Exception catch (exception) {
                Global.writeErrorLog(true, "Autocomplete text view ", exception.toString());
              }
            }); ////Remove this line also
```

Because, Flutter call the build method again when we call setState((){});  method.

Enjoy.

Comment: finally got answer.great